# Raise an exception if class attribute is set to a certain value after instantiation

Tags: python

I have a class which gets created through a constructor at runtime. Is there a way that I can prevent some of its attributes to be set to certain values after construction?

For example, in the below code, I'd like to raise an exception if the value for currRating is set to value greater than maxRating or lower than minRating. I can do that easily during instantiation, however, I am looking to do this after class has already been constructed.

```
class Machine(object):
    def __init__(self,Name,maxRating,minRating,currRating=1):
        self.name=name
        self.maxRating = maxRating
        self.minRating = minRating
        self.currRating = currRating
```

*I read through some of the previous replies on StackOverflow and understand that this might be a touchy topic for Python veterans. I am just interested in knowing if there is a non-hackish way of achieving this in Python or if this is one of those things that is not meant to be done in Python.*

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What's the difference you want to achieve between that and check it inside the constructor?

Comment: The currRating is supposed to be a property that can be changed later on. So in case it is changed to a value which is unacceptable, then I'd like to raise an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using the built in function [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)

Essentially, instead you create 'setter' methods for your currRating so that when that property is set by calling obj.currRating you can do your check to see if its within min and max:

For example:

```
class Machine(object):
    def __init__(self, name, max_rating, min_rating, cur_rating=1):
        self.max_rating = max_rating
        self.min_rating = min_rating
        self._cur_rating = cur_rating

    @property
    def cur_rating(self):
        return self._cur_rating

    @cur_rating.setter
    def cur_rating(self, value):
        if value > self.max_rating or value < self.min_rating:
            raise Exception()
        self._cur_rating = value
```

You will still access your variable as obj.cur_rating = 10

Comment: This looks to be more efficient.

Comment: Perfect. This meets my requirement exactly. I need to learn more about decorators for sure....

Answer (score 2):

Can I try this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Machine(object):
    def __init__(self, Name, maxRating, minRating, currRating=1):
        self.name=Name
        self.maxRating = maxRating
        self.minRating = minRating
        self.currRating = currRating

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in ["maxRating", "minRating"]:
            #raise TypeError, "You can't change this attribute: %s = %s" % (name, value)
            print "You can't change this attribute: %s = %s" % (name, value)
        self.__dict__[name] = value

obj = Machine("Grinder", 5, 1)

try:
    #obj.maxRating = 6
    obj.minRating = 6
except Exception as err:
    print err

currRating = 2
print currRating
```

#### You can change the print to raise an exception.

Comment: Your solution is close to what I am trying to do, however, I am trying to restrict values that can be set for currRating. I still got the idea of what to do from your solution. So, thanks , +1.